# How to disable ngx slick slider when few items?

Tags: css, angular, slick.js

I'm working with ngx-slick-slider (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-slick-carousel) and it doesn't seem to have a config to disable the slider when there are few items. When there are less items than the needed to display the carousel they displayed centered in the screen. How can I achieve this?

Template:

```
<div class="scrolling-wrapper" *ngIf="hasUsage">
    <ngx-slick-carousel class="carousel"
                        #slickModal="slick-carousel"
                        [config]="slideConfig"
                        (init)="slickInit($event)"
                        (breakpoint)="breakpoint($event)"
                        (afterChange)="afterChange($event)"
                        (beforeChange)="beforeChange($event)">
        <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let card of data" class="slide">
            <div class="card-container">
                <card-component
                        [thecard]="card"
                ></card-component>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ngx-slick-carousel>
</div>
```

Component.ts:

```
slideConfig = {
        "slidesToShow": 7,
        "slidesToScroll": 4,
        "infinite": false
    };

    slickInit(e:any) {
        console.log('slick initialized');
    }

    breakpoint(e:any) {
        console.log('breakpoint');
    }

    afterChange(e:any) {
        console.log('afterChange');
    }

    beforeChange(e:any) {
        console.log('beforeChange');
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

I`d suggest just using a for loop to count your items, then en IF/ELSE statement on what is being rendered in your view

Comment: yeah, i was thinking about that, but may be there was a config to do it. I've added the code. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways to go about this:

1. Disable the buttons in the slick config `{ 'arrows': false }`
   and then create custom elements in your template that hook up to `slickNext()` and `slickPrev()`. You can now disable those buttons using something like `*ngIf="slides.length <= mySlideLimit`
2. You could also create custom templates for your forward/previous buttons in the config using the `nextArrow` and `prevArrow` config options.

I persionallly prefer option 1.

template:

```html
<div class="scrolling-wrapper" *ngIf="hasUsage">
    <ngx-slick-carousel class="carousel" ...>
    </ngx-slick-carousel>
    <button *ngIf="data.length >= 3" (click)="slickModal.slickNext">Next</button>
    <button *ngIf="data.length >= 3" (click)="slickModal.slickPrev">Prev</button>
</div>
```

Component.ts

```
slideConfig = {
        "slidesToShow": 7,
        "slidesToScroll": 4,
        "infinite": false,
        "arrows": false,
    };

...
```

You can find more info on all that suff here: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but the problem is not the arrows since they hide when the items are less than 7, which is what's configured in slideConfig object. The issue is when less than 7 items are displayed they are centered in the screen. I know i can use ngClass with a condition and overwrite the slider classes to achieve this, but i was looking for a way to avoid doing it.